# SetCustomAttribute method does not add the specified attribute to the class

Tags: c#, attributes

I am trying to add an attribute to a class. The class looks like this;

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? TitleId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add the `TableAttribute` to the class itself. Here is my function to do this task;

```
 public static void AddAttribute()
 {
     var type = typeof(User);
     var aName = new AssemblyName("PolatDashboard.Console");
     var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
     var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);
     var tb = mb.DefineType(type.Name, TypeAttributes.Public, type);

     var attrCtorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
     var attrCtorInfo = typeof(TableAttribute).GetConstructor(attrCtorParams);
     var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attrCtorInfo, new object[] { "SomeValue" });
     tb.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);
 }
```

I am not having any compile or run time error but at the end, the attribute is not being added to my `User` class. I know that the assembly `PolatDashboard.Console` references the required `.dll` for `TableAttribute`. What can be causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Adition**: How I know that this function does not work in the way I want is by debugging. I am debuggin the code and looking the `type` variable's `CustomAttributes`and at the end of the function, it is not incrementing and the specified attribute `TableAttribute`is not being added.

Comment: Does your generated assembly have a reference to the assembly which contains `TableAttribute`?

Comment: Yes, it is referencing it.

Comment: Put that in your question, then. Your code should be a [mcve].